# Fetching the SFDC data on to sencha using equi join

Tags: php, sencha-touch, salesforce

I am using the Work orders and cases from SFDC. In my js, i have established a relation that work order "belongs to" cases. Then in my PHP file i am making the query using equi join case id as the foreign key in work orders to retrive the case number. But on sfdc side , in work orders the look up has been mentioned on the case id and not on the case number. the query fails and i am not able to fetch the required data.

This is my query. And the Work Looks ups to case i.e One case can have multiple work orders.

```
SELECT Id, FS_Account_Name__c, FS_Asset_Number__c, FS_Case_Number__c,
       Name, FS_Comment__c,FS_Defect_Type__c,FS_Description__c, WO_Status__c,CaseNumber 
from FS_Work_Order__c,Case 
where FS_Work_Order__c.FS_Case_Number__c = Case.Id 
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL does not support joins with multiple objects in the FROM clause. Instead, you'll want to traverse the object relationships from either the parent or the child. Take a look at the [API Doc about Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm?SearchType=Stem). I'm making a guess of your relationship names (they can be found in the describeSObject() results), but the queries should look something like this:

**Parent Relationship Query**

```
SELECT FS_Case_Number__r.Id, 
       FS_Case_Number__r.FS_Account_Name__c,
       FS_Case_Number__r.FS_Asset_Number__c, 
       FS_Case_Number__r.FS_Case_Number__c,
       FS_Case_Number__r.Name, 
       FS_Case_Number__r.FS_Comment__c,
       FS_Case_Number__r.FS_Defect_Type__c,
       FS_Case_Number__r.FS_Description__c, 
       WO_Status__c, 
       FS_Case_Number__r.CaseNumber 
FROM FS_Work_Order__c
```

**Child Relationship Query**

```
SELECT Id, 
       FS_Account_Name__c, 
       FS_Asset_Number__c, 
       FS_Case_Number__c,
       Name, 
       FS_Comment__c, 
       FS_Defect_Type__c, 
       FS_Description__c, 
       (SELECT WO_Status__c FROM FS_Work_Order__r), 
       CaseNumber 
FROM Case
```